# Verb Tense to use with the phrase "so far"

Tags: tense, adverbs

What verb tense should we use when we have the phrase, "so far" in the sentence?

> - How was your day so far?
> - How is your day so far?
> - How has your day been so far?

Answer (score 5):

*So far*, when indicating a time interval, indicates time from the start of something up to the present moment, with the understanding that it is *expected to continue*. Thus, it is only used with forms of the present and present perfect tenses and their progressive forms, as it would with similar phrases like *up to now*, *till now*, *as of yet*, *to date*, or *thus far*.

> - He loves Miami so far.
> - Her new car is running well so far.
> - If it rains he takes the bus, but he's walked every day so far this spring.
> - Increased spending has been failing so far, and now inflation looms.

Comment: So which is correct among my examples?

Comment: @khaleesi Your second and third examples use the present and the present perfect tenses, and would be correct.

Comment: "indicates time from the start of something up to the present moment" Doesn't it only apply to the present perfect? I still don't understand why we can use it with the simple present.